# Number of decimals in a number in Swift

Tags: swift, decimal, swift-playground

In the code below, I declared a variable by adding up different values depending on if some Toggles are true or false. When I try and print this variable it returns with a number and a single decimal after but it then is followed by a lot of 0 after it. Is there a way to display no zeros after the number?

**Disclaimer I am using Swift Playground**

```
var rvalues = [6.5, 5.9, 5.3, 4.8, 4.2, 3.5, 3.1, 2.9, 1.75, 1.5, 1.2, 1.05, 0.92, 0.82, 0.75, 0.7]


var r0 : Double {
        model.rvalues[(model.wearingMaskToggle ? 1:0) + (model.washingHandsToggle ? 2:0) + (model.quarantineToggle ? 8:0) + (model.coverMouthToggle ? 4:0)]
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you are curious where those 0 come from, read [is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) - a lot of the values in your array aren't precisely representable as Doubles.

To solve your display problem, use a `NumberFormatter` with `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits` set appropriately.

Alternatively, use `Decimal` to represent your values.

Comment: Using Decimal does not work I get the error "Cannot convert return expression of type 'Double' to return type 'Decimal'"

Comment: Of course this works in Playgrounds. When you do change your representation to Decimals in `rvalue`, you'll have to change `r0` as well as there's not automatic conversion.

Comment: How do I change the representation, is it just          rvalues: Decimal

Comment: no, `[Decimal]`. You'll also have to make sure you're not initializing your array with precise values.